# Capture some state in Haskell

Tags: multithreading, haskell, concurrency, state

I want to capture some state in a Haskell function. For instance, I have many thread trying to print on the console and I want the to play nice with each other. So I want to have some XX to make the police among the threads and I want that to be hidden as most as possible to my client.

I can think of a few alternatives, but I am not sure what is the most idiomatic in Haskell:

- Write a logger running on his independent thread, as in the parallel and concurrent Haskell book.
- Write a function like so:

  ```
  getPutStrLn' :: IO (String -> IO ())
  getPutStrLn' = do
     sync <- newMVar ()
     return (\s -> do _ <- takeMVar sync
                      putStrLn s
                      putMVar sync ())
  ```
- Separate concerns and put the said state *somewhere else*, calling `getPutStrLn` as part of a pipeline of effectual streams but not from within the threads.

Comment: Sounds like a textbook example of message passing: a bunch of threads writing console messages to a [`TQueue`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-2.4.4.1/docs/Control-Concurrent-STM-TQueue.html), and one thread reading from it in a loop and printing each message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have will work just fine:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import Control.Monad

getPutStrLn' :: IO (String -> IO ())
getPutStrLn' = do
   sync <- newMVar ()
   return (\s -> do _ <- takeMVar sync
                    putStrLn s
                    putMVar sync ())

type Logger = String -> IO ()

second = 1000000

child1 :: Logger -> IO ()
child1 log = do
  forever $ do log "I am child 1"
               threadDelay (1*second)

child2 log = do
  forever $ do log "I am child 2"
               threadDelay (2*second)

main = do
  log <- getPutStrLn'
  forkIO $ child1 log
  forkIO $ child2 log
  threadDelay (10*second)
```

You are encapsulating the state in the `log` computation - that's the perfect place for it.